# Product rule for the derivative of infinite product of functions defined on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, derivatives

Let $f=\prod_{n=1}^\infty f_n$.
Under which conditions on functions $f_n$ 
(defined on $\mathbb{R}$) do we have
$$f'=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[f_n'\prod_{k\neq n}f_k\right]?$$
I know that this formula holds if the functions $f_n$ are analytic in some open subset of the complex plane and $f=\prod_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ is locally uniformly convergent. But are there conditions under which the formula holds for functions defined only on real line (without involving analytic continuation)?